# Is there an App compatible with the "Transfer on LAN" cross-platform program?

Tags: iphone, airdrop

I am running [Transfer on LAN](https://code.google.com/p/transfer-on-lan/) to kind of emulate AirDrop.

However, I am unsure as to how to access my PC running Transfer on LAN from my iPhone 6.

Here are three things I tried, none of which worked:

1. App store search for Transfer on LAN.  nada
2. With Transfer on LAN running, I pointed Chrome on my iPhone to http://172.16.0.2 just to see if a webserver is running.  (It may be the case that my PC's firewall blocked it without alerting me that it did so.)
3. With Transfer on LAN running, I pointed Chrome on my iPhone to http://172.16.0.2:2011 as 2011 is the default port used by Transfer on LAN.

Transfer on LAN is now defunct it seems so I cannot get support from them I don't think.

Would Dropbox do what I want without having to send files over the internet or be subject to Dropbox' filesize restrictions?  I have some GoPro mp4's I want to just slide over to my iPhone from a PC that are about 2GB *each* so DropBox isn't viable for me.

Also I tried Instashare but that seems sketchy because, although it works *perfectly*, to continue past the trial, Instashare wants some information that really feels like a phishing scam.  I'm not about to give up my paypal email or credit card number to some company I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your question directly as I don't know that app. But look into Bit Torrent sync. It creates a Dropbox-like folder that exists only in your LAN, no syncing with outside servers.